# $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2}{n^2})...(1+\frac{n}{n^2})=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Here is the beginning of a proof:
Suppose $0<k \leq n$,
$1+\frac{1}{n}<(1+\frac{k}{n^2})(1+\frac{n+1-k}{n^2})=1+\frac{n+1}{n^2}+\frac{k(n+1-k)}{n^4}\leq 1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{4n^4}$.
I'm confused by the second inequality above.

Comment: Are you interested in why $1+\frac {n+1}{n^2}+\frac {k(n+1-k)}{n^4} \leq 1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}+\frac {(n+1)^2}{4n^2}?$

Comment: yes, that is what I'm confused about

Comment: Well, $1+\frac{n+1}{n^2}=1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}$ so we are interested in proving that $\frac {k(n+1-k)}{n^4} \leq \frac {(n+1)^2}{4n^2}.$ Now we get $4k(n+1-k)\leq n^2(n+1)^2$

Comment: The second inequality is just GM < AM with $k, n+1-k$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, do you mean $4k(n+1-k)\leq (n+1)^2$? And then what do you do after?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Sorry for the typo. Well, you can rearrange it to $k(n+1-k) \leq \frac {(n+1)^2}4$ and then we have $\sqrt {k(n+1-k)} \leq \frac{n+1}2$. We can rewrite this as $\sqrt {k(n+1-k)} \leq \frac{k+(n+1-k)}2$ and this can be proved by the AM-GM inequality by letting $k=a$ and $n+1-k=b$. According to AM-GM inequality, $\frac {a+b}2 \geq \sqrt {ab}$. I basically paraphrased @NaweedG.Seldon .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By AM-GM Inequality
$$\frac{k+ n+1-k}{2} \geq \sqrt{k(n+1-k)}$$

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, we have that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right) }$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n^2}+k^2O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\to \frac12$$

indeed

- $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\implies \frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\to \frac12$
- $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\implies O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\to 0$

Comment: Sorry, how do you get the first equality on the second line?

Comment: @mathnoob We have $A=e^{\log A}$ and  $\log \prod a_i = \sum \log a_i$.

Comment: @mathnoob the series for logarithm: $\log(1+x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j} x^j$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 + {1 \over n^{2}}}
> \pars{1 + {2 \over n^{2}}}\cdots\pars{1 + {n \over n^{2}}} = \expo{1/2}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 + {1 \over n^{2}}}
\pars{1 + {2 \over n^{2}}}\cdots\pars{1 + {n \over n^{2}}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{1 + {k \over n^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k + n^{2}} \over
\prod_{k = 1}^{n}n^{2}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{1 + n^{2}}^{\large\overline{n}} \over \pars{n^{2}}^{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\Gamma\pars{1 + n^{2} + n}/\Gamma\pars{1 + n^{2}} \over n^{2n}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n^{2} + n}! \over n^{2n}\pars{n^{2}}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\root{2\pi}\pars{n^{2} + n}^{n^{2} + n + 1/2}\,
\expo{-\pars{n^{2} + n}} \over
n^{2n}\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{n^{2}}^{n^{2} + 1/2}\expo{-n^{2}}}} \\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\pars{n^{2}}^{n^{2} + n + 1/2}\pars{1 + 1/n}^{n^{2} + n + 1/2}\,
\expo{-n} \over
n^{2n}\pars{n^{2n^{2} + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp\pars{\bracks{n^{2} + n + {1 \over 2}}
\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over n}} - n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp\pars{\bracks{n^{2} + n + {1 \over 2}}
\bracks{{1 \over n} - {1 \over 2n^{2}}} - n} = \bbx{\expo{1/2}}
\approx 1.6487
\end{align}

> Note that
>   
>   $\ds{\pars{n^{2} + n + {1 \over 2}}
> \ln\pars{1 + {1 \over n}} - n
> \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
> {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3n} - {1 \over 6n^{2}}}$.

Comment: Sorry, What does $a^{\overline{n}}$ mean?

Comment: @mathnoob It's the [Raising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). A shortcut notation for $\displaystyle x^{\large\overline{n}} \equiv x\left(\,{x}\,\right)\left(\,{x + 1}\,\right)\left(\,{x + n - 1}\,\right)$.