# limit of $a_n^{b_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it true that given $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=b$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^{b_n}=a^b$?  I was given $A_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nA_n}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, can I conclude $\lim_{n \to \infty}((1+A_n)^{\frac{1}{A_n}})^{\frac{nA_n}{2}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$?(Here $A_n$ is positive)

This is used to prove this:[$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{2}{n^2})...(1+\frac{n}{n^2})=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039690/lim-n-to-infty1-frac1n21-frac2n2-1-fracnn2-e-f)

Comment: You need some extra criterion on your sequences. For instance, you can't really say anything about complex or negative values of $a$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) for more details on the ambiguity of exponentiation with strange bases.

Comment: The first statement holds (At least when $a,b>0$) simply because you can show that $\log({a_n}^{b_n} ) = b_n \log (a_n)\rightarrow b\log(a) = \log (b^a)$ and then use the fact that $e^x$ is continuous (maybe it also works for complex numbers - I don't know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when $a,b\in \mathbb R$ with $a>0$ it is always true that

$$a_n\to a \quad b_n \to b \implies a_n^{b_n}=a^b$$

therefore in that case we have that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}((1+A_n)^{\frac{1}{A_n}})^{\frac{nA_n}{2}}=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

indeed

$$(1+A_n)^{\frac{1}{A_n}}=e^{\frac{\log (1+A_n)}{A_n}}\to e^1=e$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$a_n^{b_n}=e^{b_n\ln(a_n)}$$

It is correct if $a\ge 0.$

Comment: $b=\infty$ is not a convergent sequence, so I doubt that is what the OP had in mind.